# Retrieving a string value from a resource xml file using a key and getStringArray (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml

Rather than running a very large switch case with many individual string values, I'm trying to call out a specific string from an array-list.  I have the array list in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="type_items">
        <item name="kitchen_0">spoon</item>
        <item name="kitchen_1">fork</item>
        <item name="bathroom_0">toothbrush</item>
        <item name="bathroom_1">hair brush</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

In the code the user will make 2 selections.  One for a room and another for an item.  The program will then produce the item result as a string output.

```
public String result(int room, int item)
{
    String roomID = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.roomlist)[room] + "_" +
                    String.valueOf(item);

    return //needs to return "toothbrush" if roomID is bathroom_0
}
```

Now I'm trying to return from the array-list the value associated with that combination and after searching around I can't find the answer.  Maybe the answer is I'm just doing it wrong.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For a start, it’s `itemID` not `roomID` and it has nothing to do with resources, so `String itemID = room + "_" + item;`. Try iterating over the list and find the item with the right itemID then use its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you working with the Android API? It seems that `getStringArray` isn't meant to work with a `name` attribute. It just returns an array containing the items text values.

So here, if you want to retrieve a i-th item of a t type, you could redesign your resource file this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="kitchen">
        <item>spoon</item>
        <item>fork</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="bathroom">
        <item>toothbrush</item>
        <item>hair brush</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And edit your class this way:

```
public final static int KITCHEN_ROOM = R.array.kitchen;
public final static int BATHROOM_ROOM = R.array.bathroom;

public String result(int room, int i)
{
    String[] roomItems =  roomID = getResources().getStringArray(room);
    // [room] + "_" + String.valueOf(item);

    if (rooms_items.length > i) return roomItems[i];

    // Here, you can throw an exception or return null;
    return null;
}
```

The call would be:

```
System.out.println(result(BATHROOM_ROOM,1)); // "hair brush"
```

Comment: Thank you - I was just doing it wrong, this is what I was trying to do.  Thank you!!